# Word that means willing to accept whatever is given, not being forthright to tell someone what to do, even if nothing is given

Tags: single-word-requests

I am looking for a word that means "Word that means willing to accept whatever is given, not being forthright to tell someone what to do, aeven if nothing is given"

It is an adjective.

**Example**

> "I'm having trouble thinking of a new conversational topic today. We've spoken for hours. I should come up with more tomorrow. Talk to you later." Sheridon said to her friend Meena
>
> Meena replied "You should. I'm all for it."
>
> "I don't understand. I should talk to you tomorrow, or even more so now?"
>
> "Whatever you want" Meena answered being ____________

Comment: As a minor point, Sheridon's confusion is entirely unjustified; Meena's "you should" is a direct echo of Sheridon's explicit statement "I should come up with more tomorrow."

Comment: Actually, Meena's being *cryptic*.

Comment: @Hellion Sheridon thinks that when Meena agrees to him saying "Talk to you later", that she means that she wants him to continue talking to him right now and come up with more conversational topics. It is not clear whether "You should" refers to "you should come up with more conversational topics right now" or whether it refers to "you should talk to me tomorrow".

Comment: @desbest there is no reasonable way to get "come up with more conversational topics right now" out of anything Sheridon said, so Meena can't be 'agreeing' to that.

Comment: @Hellion Sometimes people speak figuratively instead of concretely. What people say, is not always what they mean. There are lots of subtleties to spoken language. Some things are implicit. If I say "There's not much we can do about it", that can mean "Let's talk about something else. If I say "I am in class", that can mean "I can't talk now". If I say "What did you come here for?" that can mean "I'm not here to have a friendly chat, let's keep it professional."

Comment: @desbest that is certainly true, if there is enough context to derive the subtext.  If you start from "Hey Bob, how's it going?  I got a few questions for you, if you've got a minute."  and get a reply of "I'm in class", the implication of "this is not a good time to talk" is readily apparent.  In the snippet of text that you posted, the implication that Sheridon is reaching is being pulled out of thin air for no apparent reason; It's a complete non-sequitur.  If you have additional context that makes his statement more believable, that's great; I'm just saying this based on what's in the post

Comment: @desbest but clearly I have veered way off course and am not really addressing the actual question you asked, so I'll stop now.  :-)

Answer (score 3):

**docile** -adjective

"ready to accept control or instruction; submissive."

Source: https://www.google.com/search?q=docile

Comment: You need to cite your source, otherwise it is plagiarism.

Comment: What is the difference between docile and submissive?

Comment: Yes but docile doesn't mean that someone will accept whatever is given to them and not ask for something forthright.